# Can I set GC heap size for RN?

Tags: react-native

Is there any way I can set the size of GC heap in RN (sort like what we do for JVM)? For some reason, I need to slightly reduce the heap size, on some memory limited devices.

P.S. we use JSC within RN, and I can build JSC from source, so change source code is acceptable to me.

Comment: Why don't you use Hermes?

Comment: Because it's not that easy to just change JSC to v8 or Hermes if you are in a super complicated online production.